# Position fixed with width and height based on content (and not 100%)

Tags: html, css, position, height, width

I have a container DIV set to "position:fixed", that includes another div set to position absolute.

Is there any way I can make this included div with the width and the height to fit the content, and not always 100%?

This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/ydSqU/

```
<div class="transparent_background">
    <div id="window">hello.</div>
</div>
```

This is what I would like: http://jsfiddle.net/3BYPu/ (without having to manually set width/height).

```
<div class="transparent_background">
    <div id="window" style="width:30px; height:30px">hello.</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aur0n,

If possible, the best and easiest way to do this is to use javascript to calculate the height and width of the elements then position the inner element accordingly.

To accomplish this, you simply take the width of the containing element and divide it by two, then set the `left` value of the inner element to that amount minus half its own width. Then, do the same for the height.

Also, one of the things you might have missed is that your inner div should be set to `position: relative` and `display: inline`. The reason your div is stretching to match the width of the containing element is because `position: absolute` takes the element out of normal flow, while `position: relative` leaves it in normal flow.

Here is the code I used (using jQuery):

```
// centering the width
$("#window").css("left", ($(".transparent_background").width()/2)-($("#window").width()/2) + "px");
// centering the height
$("#window").css("top", ($(".transparent_background").height()/2)-($("#window").height()/2) + "px");
```

With this solution, you don't have to manually set width and height. Also, having an inner div with multiple lines of text will not be a problem.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ydSqU/3/

Comment: I think nobody explain to you what  easy and simple are

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below,

```
 #window {
  border:2px dotted red;
  background:white;
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  vertical-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@aur0n change the css like this

```
#window {
        border:2px dotted red;
        background:white;
        position: absolute;
        clear:both;
    }
```

Comment: @aur0n for centered div use this #window {border:2px dotted red;
    background:white;top: 50%;left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
     margin:0 auto;}